# Jenkins display sonar results on job screen

Tags: jenkins, sonarqube, jacoco

I need to display the Sonar complexity results within the Jenkins build job screen.
I've seen the jacoco plungin I need a similar thing with percentages but these need to be displayed within the jenkin build.

Has anybody done anything similar to this?

Answer (score 1):

You're entering Jenkins plugin territory here. Check the SonarQube docs on [Breaking the CI Build](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONARQUBE53/Breaking+the+CI+Build) for how to know when the analysis report is done processing. Then you can probably use the [metrics search web service](https://nemo.sonarqube.org/api_documentation/api/metrics/search) to get the data you want to display.

Then it's time to write the Jenkins plugin. There are [some](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Extend+Jenkins) docs on the [topic](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Plugin+tutorial), but I've always found it most useful to find a plugin that does something similar to what I want to accomplish, and then pick apart its code.

**EDIT**

SonarQube 6.2 introduces webhooks, which allow you to configure up to 10 global, and 10 project-level URLs to POST to after the analysis report has been processed server-side. The post contains a JSON payload that includes, among other things

- report processing status (success/fail)
- quality gate status
- user-specified properties (such as commit id, perhaps)

Comment: [Breaking the CI Builds](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONARQUBE53/Breaking+the+CI+Build) has moved

Comment: Thanks @ChristophForster. Corrected.